# How to set adb - emulator timeout from commandline

Tags: android

I wish to install an apk on the emulator in android through command line. Thats pretty straightforward.

Now a couple of times, i see a timeout when the app is being installed. To overcome this scenarios folks have suggested we increase the adb timeout in eclipse. How do it do through commandline. I am trying to integrate deployment in our CI system.

An ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you connecting adb to a remote device or emulator?  Could you post the exact error message?

Comment: I am connecting adb to emulator, not a remote device. when i execute adb install -r package name, the emulator waits for ever and i finally see either 1) protocol error or 2) timeout

Answer (score 1):

A [post in the Android issues list](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104305) suggests using `ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=10` to set the limit to 10 minutes.